# Task scheduler program FAILS when "Run whether user is logged on or not" but PASSES when "Run only when user is logged on" and

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

**PROBLEM:** So basically I'm running a python script that only works if I'm running it on my task scheduler set to "Run only when user is logged on" and fails when run on "Run whether user is logged on or not".

[image: Showing general configuration]

**FINDINGS**:

- The error code I get in the Last Run Result when it fails is 0xC0000005.
- I know the path is right cause I copied the file within the code while debugging and it copied the file to another location (proving it's a valid path)
- I don't think it's actually throwing an error. I surrounded my entire python code with a try catch, and if it fails within the try the catch has code that'll write the error to a textfile and send a notification to my phone - but it never does that. It just fails at that line.
- The code where it fails is specifically the .load_state line:

```
plugin_path = path.join(getcwd(), 'Plugins', 'Vital')
states_path = path.join(plugin_path, 'States')
plugin_dlls = glob.glob(f"{plugin_path}/*.dll")

engine = daw.RenderEngine(44100, 512)
engine.set_bpm(bpm)
    
plugin = engine.make_plugin_processor("my_plugin", plugin_dlls[0])
state_files = listdir(states_path)

chosen_state_file = state_files[random.randint(0, len(state_files)-1)]
plugin.load_state(str(path.join(states_path, chosen_state_file)))
```

**GENERAL INFORMATION:**

- I'm using https://github.com/DBraun/DawDreamer.
- I'm running a python script (3.9) through the task scheduler on a Windows 11 PC.

**HYPOTHESIS:**

- There's something wrong with the actual Dawdreamer package. If so, how could I verify this?

Comment: I think your title is incorrect, stating that it fails in both scenarios when your question body says that the two scenarios are different. Can you align your title and question body to match please?

Comment: "I know the path is right cause I copied the file within the code while debugging" - Are you sure that your debugging environment  matches the actual execution environment? The code uses `getcwd()`. Do you control the current directory that the task runs from? At any rate, you'll have to debug the access violation, maybe with a post-mortem crash dump, or with extra logging.

Comment: @RaymondChen I set the "Start in" input to be the directory where the file is found. And by that comment, I meant I did a shutil.copy2 on the same path and copied it to another directory (and then confirmed it was copied to that directory) so the path has to be correct (I assume at least). I'll update the question with more details I have.

Comment: Just to be sure, try using a full path. Also, 0xc0000005 = crash, so the python engine itself is crashing. Maybe it can't find one of its support DLLs on the PATH? You need to debug the actual crash, because you won't be able to replicate the Task Scheduler environment yourself.